# TF Keras: AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use the following code to load a pretrained model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from config import max_letters, language_tags
import numpy as np

# max_letters = 12
# language_tags = 5
network = tf.keras.Sequential()
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, input_dim=26*max_letters, activation='sigmoid'))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='sigmoid'))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(language_tags), activation='softmax'))
network.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
network.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/loose/PycharmProjects/translate_english_german/python/network_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import hdf5_format
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 41, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 41, in init h5py.h5
AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I use *Python 3.8* and *TF 2.5.0.* I have a different project where I load a model with `tf.keras.load_model()` rather than `tf.keras.Sequential.load_weights()` which works fine. So TF itself is working properly in the other project.
I already tried a bunch of different versions of **h5py** but none of them worked. Any ideas besides reinstalling TF (because it was an absolute pain to get it working with the RTX 3080)?
[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkmIOZHjwEKPwZaGn5WGRV9NgrfZddyB/view?usp=sharing) was the weights file I used.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to install some required `TensorFlow` dependencies to save models in `HDF5` format and load back those `HDF5` file.

Try using below code to install `h5py` library to support `HDF5` file: :

```
!pip install pyyaml h5py
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
```